# Magento 2 + FastCGI (Nginx + PHP-FPM) don't work (404)

Tags: magento2.4, nginx, php-fpm

I try to use Magento 2.4.1 + FastCGI (Nginx + PHP-FPM), but I get 404 error for every page.

**PHP 7.4.15**

**MySQL 8.0.23**

**Nginx 1.16.1**

**Ubuntu 18.04**

Nginx conf:

```
server {
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    fastcgi_buffers 128 512k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 512k;
    proxy_buffer_size 512k;
    proxy_buffers 128 512k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 512k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 6000;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 6000;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 6000;
    proxy_connect_timeout 6000;
    proxy_send_timeout 6000;
    proxy_read_timeout 6000;
    send_timeout 6000;
    charset UTF-8;
    index index.php index.html;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/mysite.com/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/mysite.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/mysite.com.error.log notice;
    set $root_path /var/www/www-root/data/www/mysite.com;
    root $root_path;
    listen 178.XX.XXX.XX:80;
    listen [2a03:XXXX:XX:XX::]:80;
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
    location / {
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @php;
        }
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            expires max;
        }
    }
    location @php {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@mysite.com";
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/www-root.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.ph(?:p\d*|tml))(/?.+)$;
        try_files $uri = 404;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

And many errors in web-console:
[image]

I am newbee in it. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Older question, but when you are missing static content, you need to run

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Not sure about 404 for every page, you are hitting the main index.php file for magento in order to be looking for the static content.